# BrowserStack Live: Upload a local file

Tags: linux, testing, automated-tests, testcafe, browserstack

I have successfully used TestCafé (with `testcafe-browser-provider-browserstack`) to test my application on BrowserStack, including file uploads of local files and all.

However, I cannot get *manual* tests to work with uploads. I use the `BrowserStackLocal` binary to build a tunnel, and can access my local machine in a foreign browser through BrowserStack. However, when I use any file-open dialog on the remote machine, I only see the default set of some image and document files for upload. For real test, I need to upload the documents on my machine.

It seems some magic in the TestCafé driver transparently uploads the file to BrowserStack, so it is available there for access. How can I do the same for *manual* testing?

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar use case and identified that there is no explicit functionality to upload local files on remote machines/ devices on [Live](http://live.browserstack.com/) & [App Live](https://app-live.browserstack.com/). However, in order to achieve this use case, the BrowserStack team suggested a workaround to upload the custom files on a file-sharing tool like Google Drive/ Dropbox and download the same on the remote machines/ devices.

This works on all OS browser combinations and Android devices. In the case of iOS devices, BrowserStack supports downloading only image files at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

In the same spirit as @Dharmendra answered: When public drives are not a good option, you can always start a web server in the folder that contains your data. For instance, with Python:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

Now you can point the browser in Browserstack to `http://localhost:8000/` to download the files you need. Still, a cumbersome process.